# How to extract year from HIRE_DATE in my sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've written this

```
SELECT last_name from EMPLOYEES where year(HIRE_DATE)='2000';
```

but it shows "invalid identifier year".

Comment: `EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hire_date::DATE) = 2000`

Comment: [It helps to read the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Your column should be `DATE` (or associated) column type, not a string column such as Varchar.

Comment: @Martin [Maybe he did](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)?

Comment: Please show us table structure.  By the way, why are you comparing a numerical year against the string `'2000'`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that is best, but it wouldn't be critical to the result would it?

Comment: @Martin I think you're right, MySQL might do an implicit cast.  If so, then the problem might be that `HIRE_DATE` isn't a date.

Comment: @FrankerZ yes, a mixture of inverse case and Yagamis comment made me misjudge the SQL on first viewing, comment updated `:-)`

Comment: thanks @Yagami Light, it worked

Comment: it worked after writing "SELECT last_name,HIRE_DATE from EMPLOYEES where EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hire_date) = 2000;"

Comment: @jef it would help if in future you can use the correct tags for your question. This was a `PostgreSQL` query *NOT* a `mysql` query. Cheers

Comment: @jef don't forget to make it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a year of hire date you only have to use

**PostgreSQL:**

```
EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hire_date::DATE) = 2000
```

and for the month you have to use

```
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM hire_date::DATE) = 12
```

**MySQL:**

```
EXTRACT( YEAR FROM hire_date) = 2000
```

and for the month you have to use

```
EXTRACT( MONTH FROM hire_date) = 12
```

Hope that helped you.

> **Update Note:**
> Original question was MySQL tagged, response was said to work by Original Poster and response was given in PostgreSQL format, suspect OP should have tagged question as PostgreSQL rather than MySQL. Have clarified this answer to show both working solutions.

Comment: can you clarify the `::` operator? I've never seen this on MySQL, only PostgradSQL

Comment: But the question was marked by the OP as being `MySQL` and I don't see that operator in MySQL.... hence my comment?

Comment: @YagamiLight I appreciate your comments, but I can't see any reference on any literature about `::` being used in `mySQL`. I have updated the question to change it to the correct SQL type, as your answer did work for the OP.

Comment: @YagamiLight I have rolledback  and updated your answer with clarification for both SQL types. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Don't extract the year.  Instead:

```
SELECT last_name 
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE hire_date >= '2000-01-01' AND
      hire_date < '2001-01-01';
```

Why?  This version can take advantage of an index.

Comment: @YagamiLight . . . I have no idea what that comment refers to.  This will work for any span of time.

Comment: @YagamiLight . . . The first of the month is always "01", so I see no issue.

Comment: @YagamiLight . . . Use `<`, just as I did for the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
Extract(year from hire_date)
```

Above will work fine to get Year , simply replace year to month to get month.